# Present continuous for an event already decided

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

Imagine my friend and me are swapping  houses simultaneously  next week:I am going to his house and he is going to mine, I'd like  to know when he is going to arrive at my home.

Can I say  "When are you arriving at my home exactly?" or"When are you going to arrive at my home?"

I think  the first one is better because it has already been planned so present continuous seems for me better

Comment: Both sentences are perfectly fine and convey the meaning you want. Neither sentence is better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both sentences are correct.

> When are you arriving at my home?

You can use the *present progressive* tense to talk about firm plans that you have for the future or  arrangements which have been made.

> When are you going to arrive at my home?"

You can use *going to*  to talk about planned future events or intentions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stick with the second one, because the action (arriving) has not happened yet, nor is it in progress. If he was on his way to your house, you might be OK with the first one.

To address the "planning" issue, you could use:

> When are you **planning** to arrive at my home?
>   When are you **planning to arrive** at my home exactly?

Comment: I am visting my mother next week, we can use progressive even the action has not happened yet but is in progress  like the arriving in my question

Comment: I think "arriving" and other gerunds could be used, such as "When are you coming over today?" and "When are we meeting on Wednesday?"